# How to enable G1 gc in apache cassandra 3.11.4

Tags: cassandra

I am using apache cassandra 3.11.4 and java 8.I am  using 48 GB ram and facing a lot of gc issues.
I wanted to move to G1 from CMS and made below changes in jvm.options, commented all CMS changes.Enabled G1.

```
### CMS Settings

####-XX:+UseParNewGC
####-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
####-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
####-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
####-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
####-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
####-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
####-XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000
####-XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled
####-XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways
#### some JVMs will fill up their heap when accessed via JMX, see CASSANDRA-6541
####-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

### GC logging options -- uncomment to enable

--XX:+PrintGCDetails
--XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
--XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
--XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
--XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
--XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
--XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1
--Xloggc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log
--XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
--XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10
--XX:GCLogFileSize=10M
```

But I am getting CMS as GC. Pleases suggest how to chage from CNS to G1 gc.

Answer (score 4):

So that's happening because CMS is the default garbage collector in Java 8.  Even if you comment it out, unless you've added the G1 settings, it's still going to use CMS.

In between the CMS and GC Logging sections, there should be one more section in that file- the G1 section, which looks like this:

```
### G1 Settings (experimental, comment previous section and uncomment section below to enable)

## Use the Hotspot garbage-first collector.
-XX:+UseG1GC
#
## Have the JVM do less remembered set work during STW, instead
## preferring concurrent GC. Reduces p99.9 latency.
-XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5
#
## Main G1GC tunable: lowering the pause target will lower throughput and vise versa.
## 200ms is the JVM default and lowest viable setting
## 1000ms increases throughput. Keep it smaller than the timeouts in cassandra.yaml.
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500

## Optional G1 Settings

# Save CPU time on large (>= 16GB) heaps by delaying region scanning
# until the heap is 70% full. The default in Hotspot 8u40 is 40%.
#-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70

# For systems with > 8 cores, the default ParallelGCThreads is 5/8 the number of logical cores.
# Otherwise equal to the number of cores when 8 or less.
# Machines with > 10 cores should try setting these to <= full cores.
#-XX:ParallelGCThreads=16
# By default, ConcGCThreads is 1/4 of ParallelGCThreads.
# Setting both to the same value can reduce STW durations.
#-XX:ConcGCThreads=16
```

If you make sure that `UseG1GC`, `UpdatingPauseTimePercent`, and `MaxGCPauseMillis` are uncommented, then Cassandra should start with G1 as the garbage collector.